# How to use "specifically" as in "I have to respect him. Specifically respect. Specifically him. I don't have to love him or respect someone else."

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to use "specifically" as shown in the title? I'm not sure, I might be mistakenly trying to bring into English an element of my mother-tongue.
Is there a better phrasing?

Comment: The word specifically is not likely to apply both to specifically respect and specifically him. Except there, which is clumsy.

Comment: Would you kindly suggest a better phrasing?

Comment: "Specifically respect" sounds daft to me. What possible "clarification" could that reasonably be supposed to convey? That although I "respect" him, I don't "admire" or "endorse" him? Nor do any other words with meanings similar to "respect" apply. If there *is* a plausible "intended meaning", it's too weird for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *specific* quote (heh, sorry!) in its entirety is understandable and I could imagine it happening in conversation or fictional dialogue. But it works by its context: it starts with a normal sentence, and then uses "specifically" to further clarify it. You couldn't really insert "specifically" into similar sentences that hadn't been prepared in this way. Like, you couldn't just say "I have to respect specifically him." Even "I have to specifically respect him" is unclear and un-idiomatic, and leaves some question of whether "specifically" modifies "respect" or "him."

It might be the "I have to" construction that's making things odd here. You hear "specifically" more in things like "I specifically asked for my egg to be soft-boiled," i.e. "I asked specifically" or "I was specific in my request."